# Calling shared_from_this() from derived in base class gives std::bad_weak_ptr

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr, tr1

I've got a Base class and a Derived class. API exposes only Derived, and implementation is hidden in Base (with gcc attribute `visibility` set to `hidden`), as some of the internal API modules must call Base methods.
This way we got:

```
// Base.h
class Derived;
class Base
{
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Derived> DerivedPtr;
public:
    void doSomething(DerivedPtr aDerived);
protected:
    Base();
};


// Derived.h
class Derived : public std::tr1::enable_shared_from_this<Derived>, public Base
{
public:
    Derived():std::tr1::enable_shared_from_this<Derived>(), Base(){}
    void doSomething(DerivedPtr aDerived)
    {
        Base::doSomething(aDerived);
    }
};
```

Now what `doSomething` does is as follows:

```
void Base::doSomething(DerivedPtr aDerived)
{
    DerivedPtr lDerived = reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(this)->shared_from_this();
}
```

Problem is as follows:

- when I use a simple example as showed above - it works fine;
- when I use it in my big project - it throws `std::tr1::bad_weak_ptr` exception;

I'm using gcc-4.4.7, and of what I can see from backtrace it is called as:

1. `std::tr1::enable_shared_from_this<Derived>::shared_from_this`
2. `std::tr1::shared_ptr<Derived>::shared_ptr<Derived> (this=0x7fffffffd370, __r=std::tr1::weak_ptr (empty) 0x2)`
3. `std::tr1::__shared_ptr<Derived, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<Derived>`
4. `std::tr1::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count`

In `__shared_count` it throws, because :

```
292   template<_Lock_policy _Lp>
293     inline
294     __shared_count<_Lp>::
295     __shared_count(const __weak_count<_Lp>& __r)
296     : _M_pi(__r._M_pi)
297     {
298       if (_M_pi != 0)
299     _M_pi->_M_add_ref_lock();
300       else
301     __throw_bad_weak_ptr();
302     }
```

my __r._M_pi is equal to 0.

I know it might be a terrible idea to use `Derived` in `Base`, but that's not the matter of subject, let's just take it as it is. ( Nobody can instantiate `Base` directly ).

What's important a Client (who's using the API) is using shared_ptr, that's why Derived inherits `enable_shared_from_this`.

And what I'm trying to do is to understand what is happening and why the `bad_weak_ptr` exception is throwed and what can I do to avoid it (maybe some minor changes in architecture).

---

### **EDIT**

I changed `Base::doSomething` according to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9377075/1498245

Now it looks like:

```
void Base::doSomething(DerivedPtr aDerived)
{
    DerivedPtr lDerived = std::tr1::static_pointer_cast<Derived>( static_cast<Derived*>(this)->shared_from_this() );
}
```

and it *probably* began to work. Probably, because there's no exception anymore, but I'm not quite sure what is happening underneath. It looks like during `reinterpret_cast` there was some data loss. In my real-world case the `Base` class is much bigger, has lots of members, etc. Maybe that's the case. Can anyone put some light on this case? What is happening "under the hood"?

Answer (score 2):

> Problem is as follows:
>
> •when I use a simple example as showed above - it works fine;
>
> •when I use it in my big project - it throws std::tr1::bad_weak_ptr exception;

This sounds to me like undefined behavior.

There are two possibilities that come to mind (since you didn't post differences between your test code and your project, I am guessing here):

My first guess would be this code:

```
DerivedPtr lDerived = reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(this)->shared_from_this();
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Are you sure you are calling `Base::doSomething` from derived instances only? It is an unsafe cast to derived, from the base of the hierarchy.

My second guess is that you are calling shared_from_this for something that is not a pointer. An example of the scenario I'm talking about:

```
struct Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> share() { return shared_from_this(); }
};

std::shared_ptr<Foo> pf(new Foo);
auto pf2 = pf->share();  // OK, pf2 will share ownership with pf

Foo localInstance;
auto pf2 = localInstance.share();  // NOT OK, pf2 will attempt to delete a local
                                   // value at scope end
```

Comment: Hi, I am sure that Base::doSomething is called from derived instances only. And is called on shared_ptr. Please see my edit.